# With a Styled-Components, how to set an array of colors outside of the Styled Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

**theme.js** - I have a Styled-Components theme which contains all of my app's color variations.

```
const colors = {
  purples: {
    60: '#AEA',
    50: '#GSA',
  },

  blues: {
    20: '#asd',
    5: '#fasd',
  }
  ...
```

I then have a UI component where I need to define an array of colors in a specific order:

```
import React from 'react';
const colors = ['#GSA', '#AEA', '#asd', '#fasd', '#AEA'];
```

I later use this `colors` array to find the right color to use in my component based on state:

```
const getBackgroundColor = ({ currentPosition }) => {
  const color = colors[(currentPosition) % colors.length];
  return color;
};
```

This function is used within my styled-component like so:

```
const StyledCard = styled.div`
  background: ${getBackgroundColor};
  ...
`;
```

The problem is my colors array is being set without the styled-components theme.

How can I define a `const colors` using my theme when it is outside the styled element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have done this in react-native and should be pretty similiar. I have a file called colors.js with all of the colors then I import them as an object so that was I can say `colors[TheNameOfTheColorIWant]`

colors.js

```
export const fadedPurple = '#9f91ad';
export const success = '#4fa579';
export const failure = '#ca374d';
```

Button Component

```
import * as colors from '../../../assets/styles/colors';

const Button = (props) => {
  const {
    onPress,
    children,
    color
  } = props;

  style = {
    backgroundColor: colors[backgroundColor]
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={ style }
                      onPress={ onPress }
                      disabled={ disabled }>
        { children }
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a js file with this pattern:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var myStyle = React.StyleSheet.create({
   red: {backgroundColor: 'red' },
   blue: {backgroundColor: 'blue' }
)}
module.exports = myStyle;
```

your component js use require to use that style sheet

```
var customStyle = require('../the/path/to/commonStyleSheet');
```

Use now like this:

```
<View style = {customStyle .red} />
<View style = {customStyle .blue} />
```